# Deleting this in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, this

I'm trying to write a js function and I'd like to add a `destroy()` functionality to it. Basically code goes like this:

```
 function jsFunc(obj)
 {
    var InputControl=function(){
        //check input object for special rules.
        // i.e  obj.wait_time isn't defined, return false
    }   
    if(!inputControl())
    {
        return false;
    }
    var do_some_operation=function()
    {
        //do something
    }
    var destroy=function()
    {
        delete (this);
    }

 }

var obj={
    wait_time:100,
    //...
}
var xxx= new jsFunc(obj);

$('#button').click(function(){
    xxx.destroy();  
})
```

When I click #button it doesn't do anything. I tried to search the web, found some solutions and tried it but they did not work.

I tried these code for the `destroy()` function:

```
1.  this=null;
2. for(var i in this)
{
   delete(this[i]);
}
```

When I use one of these, it destroys the original function, soIi cannot re-intantiate again. 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: what did you want `destroy` to do?

Comment: i want destroy delete the instatiated object. if you see bottom of the first code i've written, if i click a button that i assigned, it should delete the obj. i instatiated.I aim to write the method just like bxSlider's destoy method, or tinymce's destroy method. 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.destroy

Answer (score 0):

`delete` is for removing properties from objects. Sometimes people use it to remove properties from the global object, making it look like it deletes variables. I don't think it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to destroy `this`?

JavaScript runtimes both on browsers and server-side have their automatic garbage collection processes that free-up memory for you.

Usually `destroy()` would remove some control from the HTML/DOM and initialize its state in order to let other instance of the same control work in the same scope...